# commit did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: github

I am trying to connect Nitrous.io to Github but after command git commit -m “First commit”

This is what I get:

```
error: pathspec '"commit\342\200\235"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the characters surrounding your commit message are `“` and not `"`.

A subtle difference for the human eye, but not for the shell.